# django application registry into INSTALLED_APPS should not import any models ,how to understand it?

Tags: python, django

I don't understand what mean follow, and always get error like **django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady:Apps aren't loaded yet.**,how can i do, thanks!

First Django imports each item in INSTALLED_APPS.

If it’s an application configuration class, Django imports the root package of the application, defined by its name attribute. If it’s a Python package, Django creates a default application configuration.

At this stage, your code shouldn’t import any models!

the doc is here: [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/)

[image: error info]

[image: error info]

[image: get error]

[image: domain]

Comment: what is **commonapi.models.domain** ?? show some code @

Comment: your project structure looks weird to me. make sure you have initialised the project and apps properly using the `django-admin` cli tool

Comment: @VaibhavVishal there have sub application, if i note sub application, the project run ok,but i don't understand why